# Flyway wildcard is not working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I get the following error:

```
Flyway failed to initialize: none of the following migration scripts locations could be found:

    - classpath:db/*/migrations/
```

This is what the directory structure looks like:

[image: Folder structure]

And this is what I've tried:

```yaml
# examples, obviously I tried these independently from each other
spring:
    flyway:
# these work:
        locations: "classpath:db"
        locations: "classpath:db/release_1.0/migrations/"

# these don't work: (I am getting the same error as shown above)
        locations: "classpath:db/**/migrations/"
        locations: "classpath:db/release*/migrations/"
        locations: "classpath:db/*/migrations/"
```

But they should work according to [this blogpost](https://flywaydb.org/blog/organising-your-migrations) from version 6.4. (I don't see it documented that they have removed it)

I am using `spring-boot-starter-parent` `2.4.1`, so it is `Flyway 7.1.1`.

Can anyone explain to me how to specify the migrations folder using a wildcard in Flyway and why is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Flyway's location support has grown to support wildcards, cloud storage, etc., Spring Boot's ability to accurately check the locations has decreased as [described in this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25488). As a result, support for location checking was deprecated in Spring Boot 2.5 and, after the deprecation period, it will be removed entirely. In the meantime, you can switch it off by setting [`spring.flyway.check-location`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.x/reference/htmlsingle/#spring.flyway.check-location) to `false`.